# Laravel - total record to date

Tags: laravel

I have a column named 'date' in my database and its format is ('d/m/Y'). So how can I get the total count of the date for today from this column? My code counts all dates.

**My controller is:**

```
public function home(){

    $appointments = Appointment::whereDate('date', Carbon::today()->format('d/m/Y'))->get()->count();
    return view('panel.home',['appointments'=>$appointments]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your date is stored as timestamp or datetime type you don't need to make the string format to compare it in the where clause.

```
$count = ConnectionReport::query()->whereDate('start_date',now()->today())->get()->count();
dd($count);  // it give me correct count in my test
```

UPDATED
zero is a result, not an issue. If you dd(now()->today()) you can see the date to be compared in records (eg. 30-06-2021 00:00:00). Now, please a little of logic. If you need compare the record dates that is in the current date range, you need to look for the ranges between 00:00:00 and 23:59:59. So, in that way you need to

```
ConnectionReport::query()->where('start_date','>=',now()->today())->where('start_date','<=',now()->today()->setTime(23:59:59))->get()
```

The before code, for me, get the records without specify range, but this way could work as well